# Shufle data from array for Postman pre-request script

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to create some random test data for my project, and I am trying to this with Postman pre-request script.
My problem is that I have some values in array, and I am trying to get values from them.
This is my Postmans pre-request script:

```
var images = [
      "\\advertisement\\86b37148-70b6qKhw-4ce7MZbh-a287osa0-b8fadf350955.jpg",
      "\\advertisement\\c54acd53-6caaYlaU-4e5963l2-955b0XNs-63e9376787ca.jpg",
      "\\advertisement\\86deb41e-55d82qT0-4919xLYP-9562yjcg-82b1e565c45e.jpg"
    ];

var objectHeating = [
        "NotSet",
        "CentralHeating",
        "ElectricHeating",
        "TtermoaccumulationStove",
        "Gas",
        "AtTheFoot",
        "TileStove",
        "MarbleRadiators",
        "NorwegianRadiators"
    ];

var objectDescription = [
        "NotSet",
        "NewConstruction",
        "OldConstruction",
        "UnderConstruction",
        "Upgrade",
        "ApartmentInTheHouse"
    ];

var objectPropertyCondition = [
        "NotSet",
        "OriginalState",
        "Renovated",
        "Luxury",
        "ForRenovation"
    ];

var objectOrientation = [
        "NotSet",
        'East',
        "West",
        "North",
        "South",
        "Northwest",
        "Northeast",
        "Southwest",
        "Southeast"
    ];

var objectStructure = [
        "NotSet",
        "Studio",
        "Workshop",
        "OneBedroom",
        "OneAndHalfBedrooms",
        "TwoBedrooms",
        "TwoAndHalfBedrooms",
        "ThreeBedrooms",
        "ThreeAndHalfBedrooms",
        "FourBedrooms",
        "FourAndHalfBedrooms",
        "FiveBedrooms",
        "FiveAndHalfBedrooms"
    ];

var objectBelongingSurfaces = [
        "NotSet",
        "GroundFloor",
        "Attic"
    ];

var _mainCategories = [
    "GARAZA",
    "POSLOVNI_PROSTOR",
    "STAMBENI_PPROSTOR",
    "UGOSTITELJSKI_OBJEKAT",
    "VIKENDICA",
    "ZEMLJISTE"
    ];

var _subCategories = [
    "PODZEMNA",
    "NADZEMNA",
    "LOKAL",
    "KANCELARIJSKI_POSLOVNI_PROSTOR",
    "POSLOVNA_ZGRADA",
    "HALA",
    "MAGACIN",
    "KIOSK",
    "STOVARISTE",
    "STAN",
    "KUCA",
    "SOBA",
    "ATELJE",
    "STAN_NA_DAN",
    "KAFIC",
    "KAFANA",
    "SMESTAJ",
    "APARTMAN",
    "BUNGALOV",
    "SPLAV",
    "KLUB",
    "RESTORAN",
    "KOLIBA",
    "HOTEL",
    "MOTEL",
    "SALAS",
    "ETNO_SELO",
    "SPA",
    "DISKOTEKA",
    "PEKARA",
    "IGRAONICA",
    "BROD_RESTORAN",
    "VILA",
    "VINARIJA",
    "KUHINJA",
    "HOSTEL",
    "PLANINSKA",
    "JEZERSKA",
    "MORSKA",
    "RECNA",
    "GRADJEVINSKO",
    "INDUSTRIJSKO",
    "POLJOPRIVREDNO"
    ];

pm.environment.set("subCategoryKey", _.shuffle(this._subCategories)[0]);
pm.environment.set("isRentable", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("title", _.$randomLoremSentence);
pm.environment.set("price", _.random(0, 100000001));
pm.environment.set("latitude", _.$randomLatitude);
pm.environment.set("longitude", _.$randomLongitude);
pm.environment.set("address", _.$randomStreetAddress);
pm.environment.set("location", _.$randomCountry);
pm.environment.set("cityLocationID", _.random(0, 495));
pm.environment.set("quadrature", _.random(0, 100000000));
pm.environment.set("apartmentLevel", _.random(0, 101));
pm.environment.set("floorsOfTheBuilding", _.random(0, 101));
pm.environment.set("heatingType", _.shuffle(this.objectHeating)[0]);
pm.environment.set("objectDescription", _.shuffle(this.objectDescription)[0]);
pm.environment.set("constructionYear", _.random(0, 2020));
pm.environment.set("propertyCondition", _.shuffle(this.objectPropertyCondition)[0]);
pm.environment.set("badrooms", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("bathrooms", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("toilets", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("pantries", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("commonAreas", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("orientation", _.shuffle(this.objectOrientation)[0]);
pm.environment.set("structure", _.shuffle(this.objectStructure)[0]);
pm.environment.set("belongingSurfaces", _.shuffle(this.objectBelongingSurfaces)[0]);
pm.environment.set("additionalDescription", _.$randomLoremParagraphs);
pm.environment.set("showcase3D", _.$randomCityImage);
pm.environment.set("videoURL", _.$randomImageUrl);
pm.environment.set("duplex", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("laundryAndDryingRoom", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("balcony", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("filed", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("wardrobe", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("active", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("images", this.images);
```

My request looks like this:

```
{
    "Images": {{images}},
    "subCategoryKey" : "{{subCategoryKey}}",
    "isRentable": "{{isRentable}}",
    "title": "{{title}}",
    "price": "{{price}}",
    "latitude": "{{latitude}}",
    "longitude": "{{longitude}}",
    "address": "{{address}}",
    "location" : "{{location}}",
    "cityLocationID" : "{{cityLocationID}}",
    "quadrature": "{{quadrature}}",
    "apartmentLevel": "{{apartmentLevel}}",
    "floorsOfTheBuilding": "{{floorsOfTheBuilding}}",
    "constructionYear": "{{constructionYear}}",
    "badrooms": "{{badrooms}}",
    "bathrooms": "{{bathrooms}}",
    "toilets": "{{toilets}}",
    "pantries": "{{pantries}}",
    "commonAreas": "{{commonAreas}}",
    "additionalDescription": "{{additionalDescription}}",
    "showcase3D": "{{showcase3D}}",
    "videoURL": "{{videoURL}}",
    "duplex": "{{duplex}}",
    "laundryAndDryingRoom": "{{laundryAndDryingRoom}}",
    "balcony": "{{balcony}}",
    "filed": "{{filed}}",
    "wardrobe": "{{wardrobe}}",
    "active" : "{{active}}",
    "structure": "{{structure}}",
    "heatingType": "{{heatingType}}",
    "orientation": "{{orientation}}",
    "belongingSurfaces": "{{belongingSurfaces}}",
    "objectDescription": "{{objectDescription}}",
    "propertyCondition": "{{propertyCondition}}"
}
```

And I got the following error:

```
{
  "structure": [
    "Error converting value \"\" to type 'portalnekretnine.models.enums.AdvertisementObjectStructure'. Path 'structure', line 30, position 19."
  ],
  "heatingType": [
    "Error converting value \"\" to type 'portalnekretnine.models.enums.AdvertisementObjectHeating'. Path 'heatingType', line 31, position 21."
  ],
  "orientation": [
    "Error converting value \"\" to type 'portalnekretnine.models.enums.AdvertisementObjectOrientation'. Path 'orientation', line 32, position 21."
  ],
  "belongingSurfaces": [
    "Error converting value \"\" to type 'portalnekretnine.models.enums.AdvertisementObjectBelongingSurfaces'. Path 'belongingSurfaces', line 33, position 27."
  ],
  "objectDescription": [
    "Error converting value \"\" to type 'portalnekretnine.models.enums.AdvertisementObjectDescription'. Path 'objectDescription', line 34, position 27."
  ],
  "propertyCondition": [
    "Error converting value \"\" to type 'portalnekretnine.models.enums.AdvertisementObjectPropertyCondition'. Path 'propertyCondition', line 35, position 27."
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the fix

```
var images = [
      "\\advertisement\\86b37148-70b6qKhw-4ce7MZbh-a287osa0-b8fadf350955.jpg",
      "\\advertisement\\c54acd53-6caaYlaU-4e5963l2-955b0XNs-63e9376787ca.jpg",
      "\\advertisement\\86deb41e-55d82qT0-4919xLYP-9562yjcg-82b1e565c45e.jpg"
    ];

var objectHeating = [
        "NotSet",
        "CentralHeating",
        "ElectricHeating",
        "TtermoaccumulationStove",
        "Gas",
        "AtTheFoot",
        "TileStove",
        "MarbleRadiators",
        "NorwegianRadiators"
    ];

var objectDescription = [
        "NotSet",
        "NewConstruction",
        "OldConstruction",
        "UnderConstruction",
        "Upgrade",
        "ApartmentInTheHouse"
    ];

var objectPropertyCondition = [
        "NotSet",
        "OriginalState",
        "Renovated",
        "Luxury",
        "ForRenovation"
    ];

var objectOrientation = [
        "NotSet",
        'East',
        "West",
        "North",
        "South",
        "Northwest",
        "Northeast",
        "Southwest",
        "Southeast"
    ];

var objectStructure = [
        "NotSet",
        "Studio",
        "Workshop",
        "OneBedroom",
        "OneAndHalfBedrooms",
        "TwoBedrooms",
        "TwoAndHalfBedrooms",
        "ThreeBedrooms",
        "ThreeAndHalfBedrooms",
        "FourBedrooms",
        "FourAndHalfBedrooms",
        "FiveBedrooms",
        "FiveAndHalfBedrooms"
    ];

var objectBelongingSurfaces = [
        "NotSet",
        "GroundFloor",
        "Attic"
    ];

var _mainCategories = [
    "GARAZA",
    "POSLOVNI_PROSTOR",
    "STAMBENI_PPROSTOR",
    "UGOSTITELJSKI_OBJEKAT",
    "VIKENDICA",
    "ZEMLJISTE"
    ];

var _subCategories = [
    "PODZEMNA",
    "NADZEMNA",
    "LOKAL",
    "KANCELARIJSKI_POSLOVNI_PROSTOR",
    "POSLOVNA_ZGRADA",
    "HALA",
    "MAGACIN",
    "KIOSK",
    "STOVARISTE",
    "STAN",
    "KUCA",
    "SOBA",
    "ATELJE",
    "STAN_NA_DAN",
    "KAFIC",
    "KAFANA",
    "SMESTAJ",
    "APARTMAN",
    "BUNGALOV",
    "SPLAV",
    "KLUB",
    "RESTORAN",
    "KOLIBA",
    "HOTEL",
    "MOTEL",
    "SALAS",
    "ETNO_SELO",
    "SPA",
    "DISKOTEKA",
    "PEKARA",
    "IGRAONICA",
    "BROD_RESTORAN",
    "VILA",
    "VINARIJA",
    "KUHINJA",
    "HOSTEL",
    "PLANINSKA",
    "JEZERSKA",
    "MORSKA",
    "RECNA",
    "GRADJEVINSKO",
    "INDUSTRIJSKO",
    "POLJOPRIVREDNO"
    ];

pm.environment.set("subCategoryKey", _.shuffle(_subCategories)[0]);
pm.environment.set("isRentable", !_.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("title", _.$randomLoremSentence);
pm.environment.set("price", _.random(0, 100000001));
pm.environment.set("latitude", _.$randomLatitude);
pm.environment.set("longitude", _.$randomLongitude);
pm.environment.set("address", _.$randomStreetAddress);
pm.environment.set("location", _.$randomCountry);
pm.environment.set("cityLocationID", _.random(0, 495));
pm.environment.set("quadrature", _.random(0, 100000000));
pm.environment.set("apartmentLevel", _.random(0, 101));
pm.environment.set("floorsOfTheBuilding", _.random(0, 101));
pm.environment.set("heatingType", _.shuffle(objectHeating)[0]);
pm.environment.set("objectDescription", _.shuffle(objectDescription)[0]);
pm.environment.set("constructionYear", _.random(0, 2020));
pm.environment.set("propertyCondition", _.shuffle(objectPropertyCondition)[0]);
pm.environment.set("badrooms", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("bathrooms", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("toilets", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("pantries", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("commonAreas", _.random(0, 11));
pm.environment.set("orientation", _.shuffle(objectOrientation)[0]);
pm.environment.set("structure", _.shuffle(objectStructure)[0]);
pm.environment.set("belongingSurfaces", _.shuffle(objectBelongingSurfaces)[0]);
pm.environment.set("additionalDescription", _.$randomLoremParagraphs);
pm.environment.set("showcase3D", _.$randomCityImage);
pm.environment.set("videoURL", _.$randomImageUrl);
pm.environment.set("duplex", !_.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("laundryAndDryingRoom", !_.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("balcony", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("filed", !_.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("wardrobe", _.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("active", !_.$randomBoolean);
pm.environment.set("images", JSON.stringify(images));
```